# Is the local OneDrive folder moved to Windows.old when installing a new Win10?

Tags: windows-10, onedrive, reinstall

I've had a bad BSOD issue and the startup got corrupted. I've tried many workarounds, but no success.

So I am convinced I should reinstall Win10. I need my files that are on the corrupted Windows. Particularly, I have some files in my local OneDrive folder that are **not** synced, so they only exist in the local folder, that is located in my user directory.

I tried to access these files using an recovery USB, but despite finding the folders, file names and sizes correct, I got a "Windows couldn't find the specified file" when I tried to copy or open them. Bad sign...

If I install a new version of Win 10, i.e. click Ok below, will my OneDrive local folder be moved to Windows.old so I can recover it later?

[image: Win10 Install]

Answer (score 0):

The Onedrive local folder is not affected by reinstallation,
as long as you didn't format the disk, nor does it have anything to do with
`Windows.old`.

But the chances of recovering the files are low.

You should go first for
[Startup Repair](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/27649-run-startup-repair-windows-10-a.html),
by booting from the Recovery or boot media and doing "Repair your computer".

If this is not enough (already a very bad sign), try
[Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

If you succeed in booting Windows, do this first:

1. `chkdsk` of the Windows disk
2. Check the SMART data of the disk (for example using
   [Speccy](https://www.ccleaner.com/speccy)).

This will tell you if the disk is in good enough health to keep on using it,
or if a new disk is to be preferred.

Comment: In-place upgrade, restore points, uninstall updates did not work. I tried DISM, but after many attempts, I found out that probably the last digits of the OS build of the image I was using was different than my Win10. Mine is Win10 Home OS build 10.0.19041.804, but then I couldn't find how to download the image of this OS version, it was just taking too long for me - although it could be a last resource before a clean install.

Comment: I used to check SSD health every day using Crystal Disk Info. SMART was fine, 0x0 for every meaningful attribute, and general health (based on available lifetime) was at 87%.

Comment: About the chkdsk, I'd like to point out a recent risk of using chkdsk on Win10 + SSD:
PSA: Running Check Disk Can Break Your SSD | Tom's Hardware
So I didn't do it (yet).

Comment: `chkdsk /f` is dangerous, `chkdsk` just checks. If nothing works, and you can't copy off your files, then the situation looks hopeless. Is the computer protected by a surge protector or UPS?

Comment: "The Onedrive local folder is not affected by reinstallation, as long as you didn't format the disk, nor does it have anything to do with Windows.old." How come it has nothing to do with a reinstallation, is data from my user directory automatically moved to my user in the new Win?

Comment: Yes, it is always plugged in an UPS, pure sine wave.

Comment: Windows installation is limited to the folder `C:\Windows` and some files in `C:\\`.  The Onedrive folder is not in there, so isn't affected. Before going too far, try [In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html), which is the same as any major Windows update, so isn't destructive.

Comment: I will read the whole document. In the mean time, can you tell me how can I download a specific Win10 build, so I can also try DISM? A medium grade google fu apparently win't make it... Win10 Home OS build 10.0.19041.804.

Comment: You may get specific versions at [TechBench](https://tb.rg-adguard.net/public.php). But you might as well upgrade to the latest version while you're at it.

Answer (score 0):

If you previously did not have syncing enabled, installing a new fresh install of windows will not move your OneDrive folder with it, as OneDrive is associated with Microsoft, they will automatically create a new folder by default. I hope this helps.